# Starting emacs server from outside emacs

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I am trying to start emacsserver from outside emacs (even having emacs not running at all to start with). I would like to start a search through my org files using emacs functions, but avoiding the loading of the whole init file. Is it possible?

Thank you, 
EM

Comment: No, you need to start emacs first to run emacsserver. However, you can do that without human interaction, if that's what you need (you didn't explain **why** you want to do that, if you edit your question with that information, maybe we can solve your problem).

Comment: I have edited my question. Thanks! Yes, I am no programmer, and I just need a shortcut way of starting a process on emacs (search).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the manpage (`man emacs`). Among others, there are the following options:

```
          -q, --no-init-file
                  Do not load an init file.

          --no-site-file
                  Do not load the site-wide startup file.

          -f function, --funcall function
                  Execute the lisp function function.

          -l file, --load file
                  Load the lisp code in the file file.

          --eval expr, --execute expr
                  Evaluate the Lisp expression expr.
```

So yes, you can start `emacs` without having to load the user or system init files, and you can substitute a different file instead (if needed), or you can directly call specific functions or Lisp expressions.

You can also use `emacs` in batch mode:

```
   The following options are useful when running Emacs as a batch editor:

          --batch Edit in batch mode.  The editor will  send  messages  to
                  stderr.  You must use -l and -f options to specify files
                  to execute and functions to call.

          --script file
                  Run file as an Emacs Lisp script.

          --insert file
                  Insert contents of file into the current buffer.
```

A combination of those should suffice to solve your problem, whatever it is in detail ("search through my org files" is still not very specific).

Comment: Thank you! What does it mean to start emacs in batch mode?